# Rails 2 - sending pdf via emailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.4, rubygems 1.3.6, windows 7 home basic.

Objective: to convert a html page into pdf and send it via email. (like an online receipt)

Here's what i used: prawn (for pdf) emailer (for email)

question: how to do i send an email to a real email address? All i got from the tutorial is sending an "email" that can be seen in command prompt. that's all. another question is how to generate pdf's on the fly, meaning there should be no file generated and attach it to an email? It's really hard and I have been working on this for weeks now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise answer to your question depends on precisely how you're generating your pdfs, but here's an example that should work:

1) In your controller file (as part of an action)

```
pdf_doc = Prawn::Document.new()
pdf.text "Hello, world" # etc, etc
data_string = pdf_doc.render
user = 'me@example.com'

Emailer.deliver_email_with_attachment(user,data_string)
```

2) In your mailer file (e.g. app/models/emailer.rb)

```
class Emailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def email_with_attachment(user, data)
    # setup your email as normal using @from, @subject, etc
    @from = user

    # now attach the pdf
    attachment :content_type => "application/pdf", :body => data
  end

end
```

for more information on attachments in ActionMailer see [The rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionMailer/Base)

**EDIT**: You should also make sure you've edited your config file(s) to make sure your rails app can send emails. As you're using windows you'll need to configure sending by SMTP:

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "my.smtp-server.com",
  :port                 => 25,
  :domain               => 'iwantgreatcare.org',
  :user_name            => 'username',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
}
```

For more information on configuring smtp setting see the [Rails ActionMailer guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration)

Comment: i copied and pasted the exact code, but then the email was still not sent. I'm so sorry I'm a noob at this. Can you tell me what I missed?

Comment: Okay. There are a couple of things you should check. 1) the rails log files (ie. log/development.log) to see what (if any) messages are being logged when the email is being sent. 2) The mailer config - set in config/environments/development.rb - This should point to a valid SMTP server (the other option - sendmail - isn't available on windows) - have edited my answer above to show an example config.

Comment: I noticed that the @from defines where the email is from. How can i specify the email address where i want this email sent? thanks man!

Comment: Aah, yeah, sorry, that should have been `@to` rather than `@from`

Comment: here's what's in the terminal:Processing EmailerController#prawn (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-22 18:43:45) [GET]
Sent mail to     -------> BLANK. It should have something right? What seems to be the problem?